# LSOpenApplication deprecated?

Tags: c++, macos, core-services, launch-services

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenApplication) page, the function `LSOpenApplication` has been deprecated since `OS X v10.10`. The proposed alternative is to use `-[NSWorkSpace launchApplicationAtURL]` instead. Unfortunately, I'm writing a user agent in C++ that has to launch a GUI application written in Cocoa. This means that I do not have access to Cocoa functions (including the aforementioned alternative).

What other function could I use to help me do this that is not marked as deprecated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open an application using `LSOpenCFURLRef()` with the URL of the application you want to open. Similarly, you can use `LSOpenFromURLSpec()` with an `LSLaunchURLSpec` with the URL of an application in the `appURL` field.

Comment: Can I supply arguments to the process like I can with LSOpenApplication?

Comment: Not exactly, but it's uncommon to pass arguments to applications. First, "opening" an application can mean re-opening it. That is, if it's already running, it will be activated and will receive an 'rapp' Apple Event. In that case, it doesn't receive command-line arguments because those are only meaningful at launch. Similarly, one usually communicates to a GUI app through Apple Events. So, for example, if you open a document with an app, it isn't passed as a command-line argument. Instead, it's passed in an 'odoc' Apple Event. `LSOpenFromURLSpec()` will do that for your with the `itemURLs`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the AppleEvent method!